# Most even-degree polynomials in $\mathbb{R}[x]$ are reducible

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory, irreducible-polynomials

Say $f(x) \in \mathbb{R}[x]$ has degree $n \geq 3$. If $n$ is odd, then $f(x) \to + \infty$ as $x \to +\infty$ and $f(x) \to - \infty $ as $x \to -\infty$ (or the other way around), so $\exists c \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(c) = 0$ by the intermediate value theorem, so $f(x) = (x - c)g(x)$ for a nonconstant polynomial $g(x) \in \mathbb{R}[x]$, so $f(x)$ is reducible.

The same is true if $n$ is even: $f(x)$ is still reducible. Can we prove this **without** using the fact that $\mathbb{C}$ is algebraically closed? Is there any intuitive reason that an even-degree polynomial in $\mathbb{R}[x]$ is reducible if it is not quadratic? The preceding paragraph gives a simple explanation for why odd-degree polynomials behave this way.

---

Here is a proof using algebraic closure. First, we must prove that $\mathbb{C} \cong \mathbb{R}[x]/(x^2 + 1)$ is indeed algebraically closed. Let $f \in \mathbb{C}[x] - \mathbb{C}$, and take $M$ to be the splitting field of $f$ over $\mathbb{C}$, then take $N$ to be a normal extension of $\mathbb{R}$ containing $M$, so that $\mathbb{R} \subset \mathbb{C} \subseteq M \subseteq N$; it suffices to prove that $N = \mathbb{C}$. Let $H$ be a Sylow 2-subgroup of $\mathrm{Gal}(N/\mathbb{R})$, so that $[\mathrm{Gal}(N/\mathbb{R}) : H] = [N^H : \mathbb{R}]$ is odd -- in fact, $[N^H : \mathbb{R}] = 1$ by the first paragraph of this post, so $H = \mathrm{Gal}(N/\mathbb{R})$, so $[N : \mathbb{C}]$ is a power of $2$ since it divides $|H|$. If $N \neq \mathbb{C}$, then there is a degree-$2$ extension of $\mathbb{C}$, but no such extension can exist because every element of $\mathbb{C}$ has a square root. Therefore $N = \mathbb{C}$ as desired.

Now suppose there is an irreducible, monic polynomial $f(x) \in \mathbb{R}[x]$. As $\mathbb{C}$ is algebraically closed, $\mathbb{C}$ contains a root $\alpha$ of $f$, so $[\mathbb{R}(\alpha) : \mathbb{R}]  \leq [\mathbb{C} : \mathbb{R}] = 2$. Also $\mathbb{R}(\alpha) \cong \mathbb{R}[x]/(f)$ via a field isomorphism that is the identity on $\mathbb{R}$, so
$$ \deg f = [\mathbb{R}[x]/(f) : \mathbb{R}] = [\mathbb{R}(\alpha) : \mathbb{R}] \leq 2 $$

Comment: Every pair of complex conjugate roots leads to a real quadratic factor  of the original as $(x - \alpha)(x - \bar{\alpha}).$   Every real root leads to a linear factor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is: prove that if $f \in \mathbb{R}[x]$ has even degree $\geq 4$, then $f$ is reducible. Answering this question is essentially equivalent to proving the fundamental theorem of algebra. It's clear that the FTA implies this fact, and below I will show that this fact implies the FTA.

---

Suppose that the only irreducible polynomials in $\mathbb{R}[x]$ of even degree are quadratics. It follows from the intermediate value theorem (see [Proof that every polynomial of odd degree has one real root](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/689575/proof-that-every-polynomial-of-odd-degree-has-one-real-root) for further discussion) that every irreducible polynomial in $\mathbb{R}[x]$ is either linear or quadratic.

Now consider $g \in \mathbb{C}[x] - \mathbb{C}$. We want to show $g$ has a root in $\mathbb{C}$. Take $F$ to be the splitting field of $g$ over $\mathbb{C}$, so that $F$ is a finite-degree extension of $\mathbb{C}$; it suffices to show that $F = \mathbb{C}$.

We know $F = \mathbb{R}(\gamma)$ by the primitive element theorem, so the minimal polynomial of $\gamma$ over $\mathbb{R}$ is an irreducible in $\mathbb{R}[x]$, so it must be linear or quadratic, so $[F : \mathbb{R}] \in \{1, 2\}$. Of course $F \neq \mathbb{R}$, so $2 = [F : \mathbb{R}] = [F : \mathbb{C}][\mathbb{C} : \mathbb{R}]$ implies $[F : \mathbb{C}] = 1$, so $F = \mathbb{C}$ as desired.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need algebraic closedness of $\mathbb{C}.$ All you need is that every polynomial has *a* complex root (this is proved in a particularly painful way [here](https://mathscholar.org/2018/09/simple-proofs-the-fundamental-theorem-of-algebra/)). If the root is real, you are cooking with gas, if it is complex, it's complex conjugate is also a root, so $(x-r)(r-\overline{r})$ is a degree two factor with real coefficients. Of course, since the first sentence also proves the fundamental theorem of algebra, I am not sure what the upside is. I suppose the real question is: can one prove the statement without using complex numbers at all. A couple of even more horrible ways of showing this were suggested in the answers to this: [Proving (without using complex numbers) that a real polynomial has a quadratic factor](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1677258/proving-without-using-complex-numbers-that-a-real-polynomial-has-a-quadratic-f)

Comment: I thought the definition of $\mathbb{C}$ being algebraically closed was that every nonconstant polynomial in $\mathbb{C}[x]$ has a root? There's a proof of this fact in the OP. You make a good point that any such root in $\mathbb{C}$ engenders a degree-$2$ factor in $\mathbb{R}[x]$. I'm fine with using complex numbers as long as we don't use the fundamental theorem of algebra.

Comment: @jskattt797: I think the point is that you only need to assume that every nonconstant polynomial with **real** coefficients has a root in $\mathbb{C}$. *Prima facie* this is weaker than assuming that $\mathbb{C}$ is algebraically closed.